# Set Javascript variable in a class from outside

Tags: javascript

I have a library which has defined a `class` as this. I would like to call `getMe()` function outside class `A` with my own `me`.

```
var me;
var A = function(_me){
  me = _me;
}
A.prototype.getMe = function(){
    me();
}
```

I have `class B` where I call it like

`A.prototype.getMe.call(this)` but this would throw an error as `me` is not defined. How can I pass `me` into this ? I would like to make minimum changes to `getMe` function.

The only way to do this is, I guess to use an if .

```
A.prototype.getMe = function(){
  if(!me){
    me = this.myMe
  }
  me();
}
```

So I did `A.prototype.getMe.call({myMe: myMe}, args)` but would it define the variable in global space ?

Comment: Can you create a working snippet `<>` which replicate your issue?

Comment: Your code, as written, makes no sense. For example, `A.prototype.getMe` should be outside of the constructor.

Comment: @Andy SOrry about that. Just changed it.

Comment: The code is still quite problematic, but I've updated my answer for the change.

Comment: Don't edit questions such that they completely invalidate existing answers. I've rolled back the edit, since your second attempt at posting the code was an accurate reflection of the `Map` thing (`A`) [lurkers: no, not the standard `Map`], and then added back your edit adding to the question (but changed it to be in terms of `A`/`me`, not `Map`/`myExec`)

Comment: Answer updated again, since it sounds like you can change `A`s code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't **reasonably** do this, not least because `A` is fundamentally broken (see below).

Whether you can do it at *all* depends entirely on where the `A` code is: If it's at global scope, you *can* do what you want but shouldn't. If it isn't at global scope, you can only do it from code within the scope where `me` is declared (or a scope within it).

If it's at global scope, you'd do it like this (but **don't** :-) ):

```js
// The "A" Code
var me;
var A = function(_me){
  me = _me;
}
A.prototype.getMe = function(){
  me();
}

// Your code using it
new A(); // Create `A.prototype.getMe`, because unless
         // `A` is called at least once, it doesn't exist
var myMe = function() {
  console.log("myMe called");
};
me = myMe; // Set the global `me`
A.prototype.getMe(); "myMe called"
```

> The only way to do this is, I guess to use an if .
>
> ```
> if(!me){
>   me = this.myMe
> }
> ```
>
> So I did `A.prototype.getMe.call({myMe: myMe}, args)` but would it define the variable in global space ?

Yes, it would. That's what `me = this.myMe` does.

From that observation, it sounds like you can modify `A`'s code. If so, fix it so that it doesn't define a prototype function in terms of a global variable. Perhaps isolate the code from the function into a function that doesn't expect to be called on an instance and pass in `me` as a parameter.

> I am working on an existing library to make a small change. So I can only change inside getMe function definition. And I cant change var me definition.

In that case, you can add a new optional parameter at the end, and use that if provided and `me` if not provide:

```
A.prototype.getMe = function(myMe){
    var meToCall = myMe || me;
    meToCall();
};
```

Live Example:

```js
// The "A" Code
var me;
var A = function(_me){
  me = _me;
}
A.prototype.getMe = function(myMe){
  var meToCall = myMe || me;
  meToCall();
}

// Your code using it
A.prototype.getMe(function() {
  console.log("My me!");
});
```

---

And, separately, `A` is fundamentally broken if it's really as shown (barring an **extremely** specific use-case). Having constructor code set a global (global at least to `A`'s code) that's then used by a prototype function is a huge design and maintenance red flag.

Consider the cross-talk horror:

```js
// The "A" Code
var me;
var A = function(_me){
  me = _me;
}
A.prototype.getMe = function(){
  me();
}

// Using it
var a1 = new A(function() {
  console.log("me1");
});
a1.getMe(); // "me1" -- so far so good
var a2 = new A(function() {
  console.log("me2");
});
a2.getMe(); // "me2" -- yup, still fine
a1.getMe(); // "me2" -- what the...?!?!?!!
```

Comment: I just changed with the right code. I think now it would make much sense.

Comment: Thanks. That explains a lot. I am working on an existing library to make a small change. So I can only change inside getMe function definition.  And I cant change  var me definition. And as var me is defined on top of A.js , wouldnt it be inside the scope of A even if i dont call new A(_me)

Comment: @raj: If you can change `getMe`, you're golden, just add a new optional parameter to it; see updated answer above the line above.

Comment: I cant add it as a parameter because it is a public function. If a user accidentally pass an extra argument, it would be considered as myMe instead of existing me.

Comment: @raj: That's easily handled, just make the extra parameter complex. For instance: `getMe({marker: 42, me: function() { })` then in `getMe`: `var meToCall = theparam && theparam.marker === 42 && typeof theparam.me === "function" ? theparam.me : me;`